# Specify gem version or always use the latest one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I code a RoR webapp on my sparetime. Like anybody (I guess), I use gems (about 20).

A few times, I had errors when deploying the app in production environment because I wasn't specifying the exact version for all my gems, so some of them were updated which led to bugs.

I'm worried about staying in a particular version for all my gems and when I **need** to update one (or some) of them, the whole thing break down (I had problems making gems for flying-sphinx and twitter to work together after an update).

My question is : should a part-time coder fix once-for-all the version of the gems used or is it worth the time to check each update ? How do you manage your Gemfile ?

Also I think that when you're full-time, you should always keep to date (security, performance) but is it really true ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I mostly stick with this kind of version specification:

```
gem "blah", "~> 1.4.2"
```

which means a version number `>= 1.4.2` but `< 1.5.0`

Most gems follow a semantic versioning scheme or at least only break stuff when doing a version jump. This way, I am 'safe', but still get the good parts (bug fixes etc.).

Locking down the exact version numbers is the idea behind `Gemfile.lock`, so I check this into version control, too. This approach has worked perfectly for me so far and I have never had problems with this approach.